# Custom Checkbox Design in ASP.NET (ICheck JS)

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, checkbox, onclick

Normally we're using checkboxes in asp.net pages without problem. I am searching for a solution to change checkbox's design. I found ICHECK plugin it uses js and css files. After the changes my checkbox design is well but click event is not working. Because i saw the changes like that:

**Normal Checkbox in a Project**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="atc" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" OnCheckedChanged="atc_CheckChanged" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="True" Text='check this' CssClass="icheck" />
```

**Changed Checkbox in HTML**

```
<span class="icheck" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> 
    <div class="icheckbox_square-grey checked" style="position: relative;">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$fgnbvbn$uyyy$ytyvtholder$rdghjlop$ctl01$fffds\',\'\')', 0)" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
      <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
      </ins>
    </div>
</span>
```

It hides the checkbox and creates another design and click event is not working.

Do you have any idea? Can we solve this problem or do you have better idea to change checkbox's design?

ICHECK Project Adres: https://github.com/fronteed/icheck

Regards,

Comment: Your custom checkbox has no id property,
In previous asp.net checkbox controller has an id="atc"
You shoul copy asp.net checkbox controller's id and name to your custom checkbox

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create your own CheckBox design by taking control of the HTML design as it is written to the client.

First create a class file, in this snippet `customControls.cs`. In there we will write our custom checkbox design.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters;

namespace customControls
{
    public class CheckBoxAdapter : WebControlAdapter
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            CheckBox targetControl = this.Control as CheckBox;

            if (targetControl == null)
            {
                base.Render(writer);
                return;
            }

            //checkbox span
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "icheck");
            writer.AddAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            writer.AddAttribute("name", "checkbox");
            writer.RenderBeginTag("span");
            writer.Indent++;

            //checkbox div
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "icheckbox_square-grey checked");
            writer.AddAttribute("style", "position: relative;");
            writer.RenderBeginTag("div");

            //input
            writer.AddAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            writer.AddAttribute("name", targetControl.UniqueID);
            writer.AddAttribute("id", targetControl.ClientID);

            //input attributes
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetControl.CssClass))
            {
                writer.AddAttribute("class", targetControl.CssClass);
            }
            if (targetControl.Checked)
            {
                writer.AddAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
            if (!targetControl.Enabled)
            {
                writer.AddAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            }

            //add the postback event
            if (targetControl.AutoPostBack == true)
            {
                string pbcode = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(targetControl, "");
                writer.AddAttribute("onclick", pbcode);
            }

            writer.RenderBeginTag("input");
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            //checkbox text
            writer.AddAttribute("for", targetControl.ClientID);
            writer.RenderBeginTag("label");       
            writer.Write(targetControl.Text);
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            //checkbox ins
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "iCheck-helper");
            writer.RenderBeginTag("ins");
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            //end div
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            //end span
            writer.Indent--;
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            //register for postback
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(targetControl.UniqueID);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add an `ASP.NET folder` to your project named `App_Browsers`. In that folder add a `Browser File` (`BrowserFile1.browser`). Add the following code to that file to register your custom CheckBox. Note that `adapterType` must match the namespace of `customControls`.

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton" adapterType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.HideDisabledControlAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox" adapterType="customControls.CheckBoxAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

> Note the use of
>   `adapterType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.HideDisabledControlAdapter"`.
>   Without this radiobuttons wil also render as CheckBoxes (I have no
>   idea why)